# Differences between first (initial) user and other users?

Tags: user-management

The user created by Ubuntu on install is different than the ones you create using the "Users and Groups" tool - the user is "Custom" not "Administrator".

Besides being able to "sudo", what are the other differences?

Is it just groups and privileges, or is there something else?

Does install do anything else, like creating folders, files, config, that can not or are not done using the "Users and Groups" tool?

Somewhat related question: [Users and Groups Administration tool - What do the options in User Privileges tab of Advanced Settings do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45647)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No difference that I know of, besides groups.

Creation of folders should be ascribed to `/etc/xdg/autostart/user-dirs-update-gtk.desktop`, default config files are copied from `/etc/skel` on user creation.

Comment: But are those user-dirs-update and ske1 run/copied/whatever for the other users too?

Comment: Is there any official documentation / source on this? Its so frustrating not to have easily-avaliable techincal reference for Ubuntu... anyway, +1 for the answer... if nothing else pops in, ill grant you the answer. Thanks!