# Difference between admin/normal accounts except the right to use "sudo"?

Tags: permissions, users, user-management, administrator

This may sound stupid, but I wonder if there is any difference between normal and administrator user accounts (created with the Unity Control Center) *except the right to use `sudo` to become root*.

Comment: What else does one need?

Comment: @waltinator I don't know, but I remember that when I once used XFCE, there was a long checklist with privileges that one could add or remove from an user account. Like described here: http://askubuntu.com/a/46049/367990

Comment: adding a userid to groups (`lp`,`adm`, etc) will influence programs that respect those groups. This will allow limited increases in a **user account**'s power. `root` starts with **ALL** access enabled. They aren't "privileges". They're not even "capabilities". They're just `/etc/group`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The big difference is in the amount of groups user belongs to. In addition to `sudo` , admin account has access to the following

```
xieerqi:$ groups xieerqi
xieerqi : xieerqi adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
```

That's pretty much what that settings menu in `xfce` does - adds an account to groups

By contrast , a regular user belongs only to his/her own group, unless otherwise changed by admin/root accounts.

```
xieerqi:$ groups tester 
tester : tester
```